# Unable to access key from array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I created `API` in Lavarel `5.8`. I want to access data from `$request->all()`, But issue is that, when call API from `postman` its working fine but when I call the same API from `axois` is throwing error `Undefined index: user`.

Here is my Laravel Code

```
    $userdata = $request->all();
    // var_dump array(2) { ["user"]=> string(4) "demo" [ "id" ]=> int(3) 999}
    return $userdata["user"];
```

Here is my Axois Request.

```
    data = {user : 'demo', id : 999}; 

const headers = { 
    'x-token': token, 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
    
        axios.post(`MY_URL`, data, { headers: headers})
        .then(function (response) {
           console.log('response',response)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
           console.log('ERO',error);
         });
```

I am serving the Laravel app using `Nginx`. and added `CORS` middleware.

$request->get('user') is working but i must use `$userdata["user"]` Because previous developer used `$userdata["user"]` everywhere and for every params.

Here is postman response
[image]

Comment: What does `$userdata` contain when it arrives at PHP?

Comment: How `$request` value change from `$userdata` to `$inputdata`??

Comment: i am updating my question.

Comment: Can you dump or debug and add `$userdata` value?

Comment: what does ``dd($userdata)`` return?

Comment: @Senthur, yes, if i do return $request->all()  its returning all the params that i passed with api call.

Comment: Can you add that data format to the question? Because I want to confirm It's array and It has user value

Comment: did you add the ``user`` and ``id``fields to the validation rule? @KaushikMakwana

Comment: What are the values are you passing in the header??

Comment: @OMiShah, i added var_dump result.

Comment: @OMiShah here is DD response array:2 [
    "user" => "demo"
    "id" => 99
  ]

Comment: @Senthur, i added headers data in description.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you're trying to get the user from the right variable ``$userdata`` and not ``$inputdata``? As earlier you were trying to get from the ``$inputdata`` and not ``$userdata``

Comment: @OMiShah, Yes, its same, i just changed variable name in my question, let me update

Comment: You are mentioned that It's working in the postman can I get the screenshot with values from postman?

Comment: @Senthur, Sure, Please check in description, i added

Comment: Now check the return value of `$userdata["user"]`

Comment: And another question when using `axios` what is happening when trying to return `$userdata["id"]`?

Comment: @Senthur, Yes  postman showing *demo* value in response

Comment: But in Axois its throwing undefined index user

Comment: What about id in axios?? `$userdata["id"]`??

Comment: @Senthur, $userdata["id"] throwing error.

Comment: What is the error?? same error like `user`??

Comment: @Senthur, When i disabled the Content-Length header in postman, its showing same error, is it related to Content-Length?

Comment: Yes, same error like user

Comment: Can you comment `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` and try and see??

Comment: @Senthur, When i disabled Content-Type in postman, showing error undefined index

Comment: Are you using `Accept: 'application/json'` in postman?? then try that in axios

Comment: @Senthur, i am not using Accept: 'application/json' in postman but i tried in axois but still getting error

Comment: with token add something like and see `headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  }`

Comment: @Senthur, Still same error.

Comment: Can I show your postman header value? I feel like your token adding is wrong

Comment: @request->get('user') working that means $request have user data.

Comment: sure, here is postman headers https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/11378022?key=611cd56270f8f5916b2f4bfa5535031f

Comment: change the token key like `'X-CSRF-TOKEN'` and see

Comment: @Senthur, Cookie header is automatically added, so i cant change value in postman

Comment: Try that in axios and see

Comment: @Senthur, In postman i can se only body type Row is working, form-data and other body type throwing same error like axois

Comment: Then in the axios use like `'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'` and see

Comment: @Senthur, Accept: application/json, text/plain, */* automaticaly added while i am call api from Axois

Comment: Here is Axois request headers : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/11378325?key=a479a49ba948d410fb3fd27590dedc73